# Is there a 成语 that means something like "Little dogs always bark the loudest"?

Tags: chengyu

What are some 成语 that mean something like "little dogs always bark the loudest", or "little dogs are mean"?

Comment: The smallest dogs always bark the loudest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a direct translation, "咬人的狗不叫", but it's not a 成语, it's a slang.

Similar 成语：

虚张声势: pretend to be strong to make others fear.

深藏不露: very talented or strong, but hiding from the others.

不露锋芒: same meaning as above.

韬光养晦: Hide one's capacity and bide one's time(Not sure it's a good match but similar with 深藏不露)

Comment: @user6065 "空容器发出的声音最大" is a really inauthentic expression.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some supplement to Kevman's answer.

色厉内荏："A bully is always a coward，" it literally means that looking tough outside but actually stuffed with straw.

外强中干："outwardly strong and inwardly weak。"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the English saying is: All bark and no bite, which is 光说不练

Answer (score 1):

I recommend "满瓶不动半瓶摇", which means a bottle full of water is quiet when you shake it, while a bottle with a little water makes sound when being shook. Alluding that people with rich knowledges always keep a low profile, while those people with superficial knowledge like showing off.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see this previously listed, and it seems to come close:

> [雷声大，雨点小](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%9B%B7%E5%A3%B0%E5%A4%A7%E9%9B%A8%E7%82%B9%E5%B0%8F/518874)
>   Loud thunder, little rain

Answer (score 0):

I think this is similar but a bit different from "Barking dog never bites". The Chinese phrase 丑人多作怪 would be a good translation

Answer (score 0):

人不可貌相，海水不可斗量
means
do not judge a book by it's cover